# What's the most simple JQuery plugin for this drop down thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a button that says, "Send a private message". And when that button is clicked, a list of friends drops down.

I don't want to use heavy JQuery menu plugins, because they're too heavy and are made for navigation.

Comment: Why do you need a plugin for something with such a narrow use? Why can't you just write the code? Are you having trouble writing it, haven't tried, don't know where to start? Do you have any HTML you are willing to share that you need this to work on? Very vague, broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest simply using a hidden `div` element, which you populate with the required data either in the click event handler on the button, or when the page loads. You can then use the standard jQuery functions such as `slideDown` or `show` to make the `div` visible:

```
$("#yourButton").click(function() {
    $("#hiddenDiv").slideDown();
});
```

That way, you don't need to include any JavaScript library files except the base jQuery file.